# Countdown to Shutdown

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:start
set /p INPUT=Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds? (Y/N) 
If /i "%INPUT%" == "y" goto yes
If /i "%INPUT%" == "n" goto no

:yes
timeout /t 1 >nul 2>&1
echo Shutting down in 5
timeout /t 1 >nul 2>&1
echo Shutting down in 4
timeout /t 1 >nul 2>&1
echo Shutting down in 3
timeout /t 1 >nul 2>&1
echo Shutting down in 2
timeout /t 1 >nul 2>&1
echo Shutting down in 1
timeout /t 1 >nul 2>&1
shutdown /h

:no
exit
```

When I run this, I try to shutdown my PC. I type 'y' and press enter, and it redirects to the beginning of the code. Is there a way to fix this? (There is no goto command under ':yes'. But ':no' works.)

Comment: It works here. How are you running it?

Comment: @melpomene I am running it through batch file (.bat)

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @melpomene You go into a new text file, paste in this code. Save the file as a .bat file then run it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, and the code works. So what are you doing?

Comment: @melpomene So what happens is, It starts counts, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, then after one it goes back to 'Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds?' even though I don't have a goto command, I have a shutdown -h command.

Comment: Why are you refusing to answer my question?

Comment: @melpomene I apologise, what question did you specify?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Oh, let me guess: You saved it as `shutdown.bat` and you run it from the directory the script is in. That way the `shutdown /h` command would actually invoke `shutdown.bat` again.

Comment: @melpomene Oh, I'll give that a go.

Comment: @melpomene: Nice catch. :-)

Comment: @melpomene Ok....so it worked! Thanks! But...you're saying a title can effect your whole code or...?

Comment: A filename can, yes. When you run a command, the cmd interpreter looks in the local directory for the command first, then in each directory in your %PATH% variable. Since your script is called shutdown.bat, it thinks you're trying to run that instead of the shutdown command.

Comment: Please change the question title to something specific!!

Comment: @AidenTooMLG Check my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename your batch file other then **shutdown.bat** and it will work !

Your problem is similair to this [Why does the ping command in my batch file execute in a loop](https://superuser.com/questions/298784/why-does-the-ping-command-in-my-batch-file-execute-in-a-loop)

keep this in your mind :

---

### **Don't name your bat files with the same name as existing programs.**

***Countdown to Shutdown*** `(Shutdown /h)` to hibernate the computer !

```
@echo off
Title Countdown to shutdown
Mode con Cols=65 lines=4 & Color 0A
set /a num=5
:start
echo(
set /p "INPUT=Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds ? (Y/N) " 
If /i "%INPUT%" == "y" goto CountDown
If /i "%INPUT%" == "n" goto no
Exit /b

:CountDown
cls
echo(
echo Process and Services will be automatically stop after %num% seconds..
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak >nul
set /a num=num-1
if %num% GTR -1 goto :CountDown
goto shutdown

:no
exit

:Shutdown
Rem (Shutdown /h) to hibernate the computer !
shutdown /h
```

***Edit on 12/08/2016 @10:17 Countdown to shutdown with count speaking***

```
@echo off
Title Countdown for shutdown
Mode con Cols=65 lines=4 & Color 0A
set /a num=5
:start
echo(
echo  Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds ? (Y/N) ?
Call:Speak "Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds ?" 
set /p "INPUT="

If /i "%INPUT%" == "y" goto yes
If /i "%INPUT%" == "n" goto no
Exit /b

:yes
cls
echo(
echo Process and Services will be automatically stop after %num% seconds..
Call:Speak "Process and Services will be automatically stop after %num% seconds.."
Goto Countdown

:CountDown
cls
echo(
echo Process and Services will be automatically stop after %num% seconds..
Call:Speak "%num% !"
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak >nul
set /a num=num-1
if %num% GTR -1 goto :CountDown
goto shutdown

:no
exit

:Speak <msg>
(
    echo Set sapi=Createobject("sapi.spvoice"^)
    echo sapi.Speak("%~1"^)
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b

:Shutdown
Call:Speak "We Shutdown the computer !" 
shutdown /h
```